# How to join two table one of them has duplicate of ID

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, one of them has duplicate IDs and one of them has distinct. I struggle to join those tables to get desired result as show below:
Table 1

| id | Country | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | Boston |
| 1 | USA | Detroit |
| 2 | Mexico | Mexico City |
| 2 | Mexico | Tijuana |
| 3 | Canada | Toronto |
| 3 | Canada | Vancouver |

Table 2

| id | Country | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | Open |
| 2 | Mexico | Closed |
| 3 | Canada | Open |

I would like to get the result looks like following:

| id | Country | City | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | Boston | Open |
| 1 | USA | Detroit | Open |
| 2 | Mexico | Mexico City | Closed |
| 2 | Mexico | Tijuana | Closed |
| 3 | Canada | Toronto | Open |
| 3 | Canada | Vancouver | Open |

Comment: This looks like a very simple `JOIN`. What did you try, and why didn't it work?

Comment: It looks like Table 1 has redundant columns. It doesn't need both `id` and `Country`, since they duplicate what's in `Table 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a basic `JOIN`?

```
select t1.*, t2.status
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```